# Swift: Positioning Children of the SKCameraNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skcameranode

**Context**:

- there is a *cursor* (like your mouse) `SKSpriteNode`
- *cam* is a `SKCameraNode` and is a child to the cursor (i.e. wherever your cursor goes, so follows the camera).
- cam is *purposely* not centered on the cursor; rather, it is offset so the cursor appears at the top of the view, and there remains empty space below

A simple schematic is given below
[image]

**Goal**:
The goal is two add to sprites to the lower left and lower right corners of the camera's view. The sprites will be children of the camera, so that they always stay in view.

## Question

How can I position a sprite in the corner of a camera, especially given that the `SKSpriteNode` does *not* have an `anchorPoint` attribute (as an `SKSpriteNode` typically has, which let me offset the camera as a child to the cursor)?

Note: One can position the `SKSpriteNode`s on the `GameScene` and then call `.move(toParent: SKNode)`, which gets you closers but also messes with the position and scale of the `SKSpriteNode`s

```
var cam: SKCameraNode!
let cursor = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cursor")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        // Set up the cursor
        cursor.setScale(spriteScale)
        cursor.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: raisedPositioning)
        cursor.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5)
        cursor.zPosition = CGFloat(10)
        addChild(cursor)

        // Set up the camera
        cam = SKCameraNode()
        self.camera = cam
        cam.setScale(15.0)
        
        // Camera is child of Cursor so that the camera follows the cursor
        cam.position = CGPoint(x: cursor.size.width/2, y: -(cursor.size.height * 4))
        cursor.addChild(cam)

        // Add another sprite here and make it child to cursor
        ...
```

Comment: Please post the minimal code that can reproduce the issue. That way you will likely get your answer faster. Also you may want to fix this part of a sentece : "especially given the SKSpriteNode does not have an anchorPoint attribute "

Comment: @Whirlwind M.W.E was not included as the issue was described for an M.W.E. (That image isn't from my actual code, but an MWE).  Nonetheless I added some minimum code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best solved with a "dummy node" that acts as the camera's screen space coordinates system.

Place this dummy node at the exact centre of the view of the camera, at a zPosition you're happy with, as a child of the camera.

**[...from SKCameraNode docs page:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skcameranode)**

> The scene is rendered so that the camera node’s origin is placed in
>
> ### the middle of the scene.

Attach all the HUD elements and other pieces of graphics and objects you want to stay in place, relative to the camera, to this dummy object, in a coordinate system that makes sense relative to the camera's "angle of view", which is its frame of view.

[**...from a little further down the SKCameraNode docs page:**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skcameranode)

> The camera’s viewport is the same size as the scene’s viewport
>   (determined by the scene’s size property) and the scene is still
>   scaled by its scaleMode property when it is rendered into the view.

Whenever the camera moves, it moves the dummy object, and all the children of the dummy object move with the dummy object.

The biggest advantage of this approach is that you can shake or otherwise move the dummy object to create visual effects indicative of motion and explosions. But also a neat system for removal from view, too.

Comment: Ok, but how do I know where the center of the Camera is? Is that position? Also, how wide is the Camera? it does not have the property `size`.

Comment: @SumNeuron see updates above, and the SKCameraNode page here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skcameranode

Comment: in the question it is mentioned that the camera is: 1.) offset and 2.) child to a SKSpriteNode, this is what makes positions things on the camera tricky as, they do not appear where, in theory, one would think that they would relative to the camera's position which is anchored to a sprite.

Comment: It's not the camera that's offset. It's the content. The camera can't actually be offset. Hence my mentioning of using a dummy. The dummy can be offset, shaken, rotated, etc.

Comment: Use the dummy as the parent of your content, then move the dummy as required to shift things where you need. I am impressed with your tone of authority, though, despite your naivety.

Comment: I suspect you're probably a good programmer, with great experience, in another field of coding, but new to game engines and virtual cameras. Or similarly experienced in another field. But SK requires a degree of reading and mastery before it all clicks because there's no overview made available of how it all fits together. and the "logic" that underpins its piecemeal "design". This is a hodgepodge of ideas from various game engines. It's not theoretically possible to understand it "in theory" because there's not much cohesion to the whole of SpriteKit. It's a bubble & squeak production.

Comment: So, to continue this, the SKScene anchor/origin you set in the .sks file (or in code in your GameScene style class) has an influence on how the camera's view's coordinates work. If the anchor/origin of your scene is in the middle (0.5, 0.5) then you need to use positive and negative numbers to cover the whole screen, like cartesian coordinates. If your origin is at the bottom left, you need to use only positive values in x and y to cover the whole screen. And you need to know the range of values available, too, for each device.

Comment: Only with this combined knowledge of the screen frame.size, and the origin, can you put things where you "expect" them to be with literal values. Otherwise you can use division of the frame.size to find relative positions, relative to the origin/anchor position you're using. So eat a little humble pie and realise you have to actually understand how all the bits and pieces play together before you can ask a question with sufficient provision of detail, phrased well enough to get a literal, code based, absolute answer. At which point you can probably answer the question yourself, ironically.

Comment: that makes sense... I think... So in other words, although the camera has a position offset from the anchor of its parent sprite, the camera itself is not offset.  If a) a dummy node resolves this b) HUDs in games are not uncommon, and c) SKCameraNode inherits from SKNode as does, how come the SKCameraNode is not just given an anchor point for positioning for such elements?

Comment: It is. Most people simply add their HUD elements to the camera node, as children of that. But because you not only want an offset, but also want the "pointer" to be the primary object of "focus", you're better off getting one more level of abstraction, ie use a dummy object, so you have one literal space (that of the dummy object) that you can then offset in its relationship to the camera. In this way, everything on the "screen" of the dummy object is in screen space values, and the dummy object is then offset in its relationship to the camera. Giving you the desired result with minimum effort

Comment: also I already have all the various ranges of values for the screen sizes and position my elements dynamically relative to the screen size (depending on how much room, etc), it is only when I try to add them to the camera that is causes issue. Positioning, otherwise, is as desired. Regardless, I do appreciate your thorough explanation.

Comment: See the above comment about WHY to use the dummy, so your screen space realisations ONLY need to be using a dummy, that's then offset relative to the camera, to get your ideal result.

Comment: The camera provides a "windowed view" into the world you build in your SKScene. Dummy objects are powerfully used in 3D software as tools for offsets and virtualisation of relationships to benefit ease of positioning. Lights and cameras, in 3D, need a target object. This is usually somewhat of a dummy. 2D has no target, its direction is presumed to be straight down, its view presumed straight on. You're not doing that, hence the advantage of using a dummy as the offsetting device.

Answer (score 3):

the cameraNode has no size, but you can get the current screen size with the frame property

```
frame.size
```

then you can position your node accordingly, for example if you want to position the center of `yournode` in the left corner you set the position as this:

```
yournode.position.x = 0
yournode.position.y = frame.size.height
```